# How to arrange labels and input in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to arrange inputs and labels horizontally.

I tried:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

           <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    <h2>Label1:</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input id="Filter_1" />
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                    <h2>Label2:</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                    <input id="Filter_2" />
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <h2>Label3:</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <input id="Filter_3" />
                </div>
                <div class="span1">
                    <input id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-large" value="Button 1" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

But the result was terrible with all this in the left side of the screen while the right side completely blank:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any CSS posted. Add it using the snippet tool (Include your HTML there as well).

Comment: I`m using bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use bootstrap you can use this layout.

**Run code and open it in full page mode.**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <label>Label1:</label>
      <input id="Filter_1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <label>Label2:</label>
      <input id="Filter_2" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <label>Label3:</label>
      <input id="Filter_3" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-btn">
      <input id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="Button 1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can find more guidance and example in [**forms-horizontal in bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: I want everything in the same line.

Comment: Did you see my executed code in Full page mode? it's a single row form elements!!!

Comment: @kadzu would you select my answer as correct or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think the attribute you are searching for is **float**. Add to your CSS:

```
.span1, .span2 {
    float: left;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: This is my span2 class
.span2 {
  width: 140px;
}

Comment: You are using bootstrap which is causing the other stuff. Have you tried using the _float_ attribute?